# Insert Key for Sage

Tags: macos, keyboard

I want to insert a line in my Sage software.  What do I use for an insert key?
Thanks.  Please just answer if you actually have done it, because some of these other answers do not actually work.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  If you don’t get good answers, consider editing the post to show your research. Listing how you searched, what other answers you found and why they didn’t work will help us help you. Maybe a link to sage software would help as well.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> had worked for old (before 2013) MBAs. However, it seems no key combination for recent macs. You can use third party remap tool like [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to remap <kbd>INSERT</kbd>